# Would Changing fstab file entry to rw put data on Hard Drive at risk?

Tags: usb, mount, linux-mint

On my Linux Mint 16 Petra, I have encountered a problem where the USB's are inaccessible and the wireless is not getting turned on. Also Kdesu Konsole will not display. It says in the tray that it is active, but there is no gui.

Over the past day and a half I have found the kern.log, the boot.log and explored init and etc versions of fstab file.

As far as the info the system provides as it starts up, it issues one notice that
KDE Power Management Service is not on because "no backend module" can be found... which I guess accounts for the battery icon not being present.

In the logs, is /var/log/boot.log is a line:

> /scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 1: can't open /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: no such file

However, every time I look, that file DOES exist in the named place!

Now, final bit of intel I have gathered is the system is at runlevel N 2.

I have established that the laptop's hardware is not at fault; I am able to run a copy of Mint from CD, and it makes the USB's available and the wireless services work.  Pretty much narrows it down to something having gone wrong with the current install having been hurt somehow.  I really would like to get the data secured.  So I am hoping to at least figure out how to mount a USB for backup purposes at a minimum, before I consider doing a complete
re~install if that is needed in the end.

My apologies if it took a while to get to the question itself:  if I change an
entry in /etc/fstab, for the options to the / root filesystem, from this:

> /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root  /        ext4      errors=remount-ro     0     1

to this:

> /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root  /        ext4       errors=remount-rw      0     1

going on the idea it would start up then in a higher runlevel and make the USB
accessible.

Only thing is, I am a little cautious about making that change. Does anyone know if it would put the data at risk or is it safe and worth a try?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What that option does is to remount the root partition as read-only if `mount` encounters any errors. If there is an issue with the filesystem, trying to write to it could result in data loss. In your case, though, the problem is not related to this (your system would not be able to complete the boot process if the entire root filesystem were read-only). So it is unlikely to have any effect on your issues with the wireless  and the USB ports.

Comment: Okay, thanks, something to consider as I dig deeper into it, then

Comment: LOL It was a bad idea.  Very bad!